# How can I replace my corrupted user's .profile in Ubuntu 18.04 with default?

Tags: 18.04

I think that my user's `~/.profile` has been corrupted.

Can anybody tell me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
mv $HOME/.profile $HOME/.profile.bak
```

This moves your broken profile

```
cp /etc/skel/.profile  $HOME/
```

this copies a profile with untouched content.